# How to fetch the string "Hi there" from the below array in unix

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I only want to fetch Hi there and store it in a variable VAR1. So basically VAR1 should contain Hi there

```
VIEW_COL[1]="Hi there,USA,Y"
```

This is what i have tried so far.

```
Column_Display_Name=`echo ${VIEW_COL[$LoopViewCol]}|cut -d"," -f1|sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//'`
```

But since there is a space between "hi" and "there" my command is not able to handle. Please help and let me know if i have asked something wrong in the question.

Comment: This part `echo ${VIEW_COL[$LoopViewCol]}|cut -d"," -f1` returns `Hi there` (if $LoopViewCol==1). What do you want/expect the sed part to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `bash`, you can use parameter expansion:

```
echo ${VIEW_COL[1]%%,*}
Hi there
```

`%` means remove from the right, `%%` means greedily, `,*` is the pattern to remove.